# VBA Loop is for spliting text and is very slow(Not responding maybe) Would need some help on improvement?

Tags: excel, vba, string, loops, split

Inside columns A1: A10000 are all filled with 18 chars string
Eg: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

The following VBA will help split them into their respective columns according their specific length of char needed. However VBA might not be respond due to large amount of information. Would need some help on improvement?

```
Sub looptest()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cCel As Range
    Dim i As Long

Set rng = Range("A1: A10000")

   i = 1


    For Each cCel In rng
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 2)
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 3, 1)
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 4, 2)
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 6, 1)
        Cells(i, 6).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 7, 2)
        Cells(i, 7).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 9, 2)
        Cells(i, 8).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 11, 3)
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 14, 1)
        Cells(i, 10).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 15, 3)
        Cells(i, 11).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 16, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Next cCel


End Sub
```

Comment: It might help improve run time duration of your code by including `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual' before your `For...Next` loop and then set them back to `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic' - [This spreadsheetguru article](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/2/25/best-way-to-improve-vba-macro-performance-and-prevent-slow-code-execution) can help explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using variant array is fast.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Set rng = Range("A1: A10000")
    vDB = rng

    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n, 1 To 10)

    For i = 1 To n
        vR(i, 1) = Left(vDB(i, 1), 2)
        vR(i, 2) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 3, 1)
        vR(i, 3) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 4, 2)
        vR(i, 4) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 6, 1)
        vR(i, 5) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 7, 2)
        vR(i, 6) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 9, 2)
        vR(i, 7) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 11, 3)
        vR(i, 8) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 14, 1)
        vR(i, 9) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 15, 3)
        vR(i, 10) = Mid(vDB(i, 1), 16, 1)
    Next i
    Range("b1").Resize(n, 10) = vR
End Sub
```

Comment: Code debug at ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n, 1 To 10) ??Subscript out of range. Sry i am not familiar with variant

Comment: @Clifford, I mistyped `n = UBound(vDB, 1)` .  i edited.

Comment: @Clifford, Even if you are not familiar with the variant array, it is inevitable that this is fast.

Comment: It certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

Before the for loop, add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and after that,

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop

```
Sub NoLoop()

    TurnOffFunctionality()

    Range("O1") = Now()  ' start time

    Range("B1:B10000").Formula = "=Left(RC[-1],2)"
    Range("C1:C10000").Formula = "=Mid(RC[-2],3,1)"
    Range("D1:D10000").Formula = "=Mid(RC[-3],4,2)"
    Range("E1:E10000").Formula = "=Mid(RC[-3],6,1)"
    ' Leave it to the OP to continue

    ' and if you want the values only uncomment the following line
    ' Range("B1:E10000").Value = Range("B1:E10").Value


   TurnOnFunctionality

End Sub
```

And if you want to speed this up you could also turn of some functionalites first with the following code

```
' Procedure : TurnOffFunctionality
' Source    : www.TheExcelVBAHandbook.com
' Author    : Paul Kelly
' Purpose   : Turn off automatic calculations, events and screen updating
Private Sub TurnOffFunctionality()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

' Procedure : TurnOnFunctionality
' Source    : www.TheExcelVBAHandbook.com
' Author    : Paul Kelly
' Purpose   : turn on automatic calculations, events and screen updating
Private Sub TurnOnFunctionality()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for yr advice